# When i tried to include recycler and card view dependecies it shows this support libarary should not different version

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joshua.exigent"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ITS

Comment: all support library should be same version

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same version so, change your `gradle` file to this:

```
defaultConfig {


      applicationId "com.example.joshua.exigent"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies { compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' 
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7::23.4.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all support library versions same i.e **23.4.0**

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```